How to layer photos on top of watermark with ImageMagick?
I am a photographer working on a project which in the end will result in some photos I'm going to post on social media.
But in doing this I want to format some photos with a template I made to make each image square resulting in a square picture to post.
For example, a picture of my cat:

Or some cherry blossoms I took a photo of:

The photos are all their respective sizes and I have two templates (one for vertical images and one for horizontal images) which look like this; the grey represents a transparent area:



And what is the exact question here? What did you try, how did it fail?

You'd use the magic composite command. Let's use example file names of base.png and overlay.png, with an output name of result.png.
In the most simple scenario where the both are the same resolution, you could simply do:

magick composite overlay.png base.png result.png

If the images are different sizes and you want to place the watermark in a specific spot, you'd use the gravity argument to place it, where the value can be a cardinal direction like northeast or center. Like:

magick composite -gravity northeast overlay.png base.png result.png

If the images are different sizes and you want to resize the overlay to match the base (assuming both have the same aspect ratio), you'd need to add in the resize command with some effects:

magick base.png overlay.png -resize %[fx:u.w]x%[fx:u.h] -composite output.png

In the resize arguments there, the u.w and u.h parts of the resize argument refer to the width and height of the first image mentioned (in this case base.png).
If you have a watermark that you want to keep small and use as like a corner watermark, and always keep relative to the size of the base image, you could do something similar with the geometry argument like this:

magick base.png overlay.png -geometry %[fx:u.w/8]x%[fx:u.h/8]+0+0 -gravity southeast -composite output.png

Where the u.w/8 sets the size of the overlay to 1/8th the size of the base image, and the -gravity southeast puts it on the bottom right corner.
